# imported data through vba code to insert 1 row higher

Tags: vba, excel

I want my code that imports data from other workbooks to the bottom of a specific worksheet in my currently used workbook to insert 1 row higher because of the grand totals on the bottom of the table. how should my code be altered to achieve this?

```
Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FileToOpen As String

On Error Resume Next
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Choose Excel File to Import", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xl?? (*.xl??),")
If FileToOpen = "False" Then
MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Exit Sub
Else
Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook: Set ws1 = wbk1.Sheets("BOM-DB")
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileToOpen)
DoEvents
Set ws2 = wbk2.Sheets(1)

 With ws2
    .Range("A2", .Range("AA" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
    ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Range("A:A").Find("*", ws1.Range("A1") _
        , , , , xlPrevious).row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
End If
wbk2.Close False
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

[From Link](http://www.excel-vba.com/vba-code-2-6-cells-ranges.htm)
"To move one cell down (from B2 to B3): Range("B2").Offset(1,0).Select"

By altering code and removing `.Offset(1, 0)` as this is saying move down by 1 row.

Also it is good coding practice to remove `On Error Resume Next` from top of code and only error trap something you really want to check against. As this is saying if you find any error ignore it, until you come to stopping error trapping at `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: sorry. i've just looked at my table again and it overwrote my values on the bottom instead of inserting it in between.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks familiar. :)
Anyways, you can try below but this will copy the data exactly as is and not as Values only.

```
ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Range("A:A").Find("*", ws1.Range("A1") _
    , , , , xlPrevious).row).Insert xlDown
```

Comment: hi again. lol. didnt want to bother you again a while ago so i made a new question. :) i've tried your code but it didnt insert in the table.

Comment: it doesnt do anything. or I dont see anything happening. . .